# iPHONE IOS SDK odd warning in PCH file

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I don't think I'm giving any Apple secrets away here, so I'll ask.
My .pch file looks like this:

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <Availability.h> 
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "DejaViewAppDelegate.h"
#endif
```

So, a warning appears on line 2 that says "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later.".

The SDK warning is echoing the ifndef warning when  #import Availability.h comes AFTER the ifndef statement. 
It does NOT throw a warning when the #import Availability.h BEFORE the idndef.

Any reason why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the standard project template, `<Availability.h>` is the first import. That makes sense because that's where `__IPHONE_4_0` is defined.

The macro at the top checks if `IPHONE_4_0` is defined and issues a compiler warning if it's not. As the macro is defined later (by importing `<Availability.h>`, you see the compiler warning.